# Изменение имени потока в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Создаю поток вот так, создавая новый объект `Thread`

```
public void my_method()
{

    //тут делаю всякие свои действия

    //Создание потока
    Thread thr1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          //исполняемый код
        }
    });

  //тут запускаю поток
  thr1.start(); 

}
```

Нужно создавать много потоков, которые будут одновременно решать одну и ту же задачу, но с разными исходными данными.

Т.е. нужно создать потоки от `thr1` до `thr100`. Копировать в исходном коде потоки и давать им имена от 1 до 100(а в будущем их может быть и больше) - явно не выход.

**Нужно как-то сделать, чтобы имя потока создавалось по такому принципу:**

```
i = i + 1
имя_потока = "thr"+i;

Thread имя_потока = new Thread...
...
```

**Но как это реализовать на практике?**

При этом поток управляется из того же класса, где и создается, и терять эту возможность не хотелось бы.

Как вариант, можно наследоваться от класса `Thread`, но тогда поток нужно создавать в отдельном классе, что очень неудобно в мой ситуации. Или можно обойтись без отдельного класса? Но как?

Comment: именование через setName не нужно? `public void run() {
            Thread.currentThread().setName("My custom name here");
}` ......еще хотелось бы знать зачем столько переменных или именование нужно вообще? Чтобы что? И не хотите ли использовать пул потоков?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский по поводу setName - не уверен что это то, что нужно для реализации моей задачи. Но за идею спасибо, обязательно попробую. Вообще это я делаю многопоточное приложение для работы сразу с несколькими аккаунтами некоторого сервиса. Про пул потоков джае не знал, буду гуглить.

Comment: Если не рассматривать пул потоков, то кто вам мешает массив завести и запустить 100 потоков в цикле?

Comment: @Russtam я не понимаю как используя массив и циклы запустить 100 потоков, при этом выдав им разные данные.

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ ниже, это как пример. Правильнее такие вещи делать с помощью ExecutorService.

Answer (score 5):

Могу предложить следующее решение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10, new CustomThreadFactory());
    executorService.submit(() -> {
            //что то там
    });
 }

private static class CustomThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
    private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final String prefix = "th";

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable task) {
        return new Thread(task, prefix + counter.incrementAndGet());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант:

Наследуешь класс `Thread`:

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {
    private static int id = 0;

    public MyThread(Runnable target) {
        super(target, "thr " + id++);
    }
}
```

Ну, а дальше:

```
MyThread thr1 = new MyThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      //исполняемый код
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто:

```
private i = 1;

public void my_method()
{
    //тут делаешь всякие свои действия

    //Создание потока
    Thread thr = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          int data = Integer.valueOf(getName());
          //исполняемый код
        }
    }, i++);

  //тут запускаешь поток
  thr.start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно создать 100 потоков в цикле и передать данные (см. dataForThread, как пример)

Класс имплементирующий Runnable:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private int dataForThread;

    public MyRunnable(int dataForThread) {
        this.dataForThread = dataForThread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(dataForThread);
    }
}
```

Создаем и запускаем 100 потоков:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[100];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        threads[i] = new Thread(new MyRunnable(i), "MyThread " + i);
        threads[i].start();
    }
    //TODO ждем когда потоки закончат работу, можно в цикле через join()
}
```